# multiple row bar chart using Morris.js

Tags: php, jquery, html, bar-chart, morris.js

i'm working on a project and below is the following code i am using to make a bar chart.
the db table named bar contains, id, factor, score, goal_1, goal_2, goal_3 attributes. 
i am not getting an error, but the chart is not showing and blank page is displayed to me.

```
<?php 
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","chart");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM bar";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $chart_data = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $chart_data .="{ factor:'".$row["factor"]."', goal_1:'".$row["goal_1"]."', goal_2:'".$row["goal_2"]."', goal_3:'".$row["goal_3"]."'},";
    }
    $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>bar chart project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
Morris.bar({
    element: 'chart',
    data: [<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
    xkey: 'factor',
    ykeys: ['goal_1','goal_2','goal_3'],
    labels: ['goal_1','goal_2','goal_3'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, please give us the dataset so that we could reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the columns within the query

```
$query = "SELECT factor, goal_1, goal_2, goal_3 FROM bar";
```

and add a this to your code

```
<div id="chart" class="chart" style=<your preferred dimensions></div>
```

Comment: if the error still persists write down this below your code

Comment: your sql query code 
if (!$result){
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connect));
  exit();
}